# How to insert in set at specific index

Tags: dart

I have a set in my program

```
Set<MyObject> set = {};
```

after inserting some values

```
set.add(object);
```

how do i insert in the set at index 0?

```
set.insert(index, object,);
```

(insert does not exists in set class) https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.8.4/dart-core/Set-class.html

Comment: A Set is unordered, hence no indexing.  Maybe you need a [List](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.8.4/dart-core/List-class.html)  instead?

Comment: @OldProgrammer Actually, the default implementation for `Set` is a `LinkedHashSet`, which uses insertion order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following OldProgrammer's suggestion, you must use `List`. However, I can see that there is a requirement of not inserting the duplicate, hence you are using a `set`. For that, what you can do is, you can use `in` operation in the loop and insert accordingly.

```dart
List<MyObject> data = [];

// you can add your object to the list with the check whether 
// it is already there
if(object in data){
  print('Already there');
}else{
  data.insert(index, object);
}

//print the data to check
print(data);
```

I hope this gives you some clarity, and get what you're desired to get.

Comment: i was using a different workaround (an additional set), but this is a cleaner option thanks @alok

Comment: No problem @lino arango. Keep learning! All the best :)

Answer (score 1):

By default `Set` is a `LinkedHashSet`, which stores items in insertion order.

As [Alok suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63077005/179715), using a `List` instead of a `Set` would give you full control over element order, but it would come at the cost of needing to check for element uniqueness yourself.  Consequently, insertions, removals, and lookups each would be O(n) instead of the usual O(1).  If you frequently need to remove elements or frequently need to check if an element already exists, this would not be an efficient solution.

If you don't need *full* control over element order, you might be able to continue using a `Set`.  To force an item to be at the beginning, you would need to remove and re-add all *other* items.  One way to do that would be to create a new `Set`:

```dart
set = <MyObject>{object, ...set};
```

If you need to mutate an existing `Set`, you could add an extra step:

```dart
var temporarySet = <MyObject>{object, ...set};
set..clear()..addAll(temporarySet);
```

Note that in both cases, insertion would have runtime complexity of O(n) instead of the usual O(1).  Removals and lookups would remain O(1).

If you need to insert at the beginning frequently and *only* at the beginning, you possibly could cheat by always iterating over the `Set` *backwards*, treating the last element as the first:

```dart
// Force `object` to be last.
set..remove(object)..add(object);
```

and then use `set.last` instead of `set.first` or use `set.toList().reversed` when iterating.  This would allow insertions, removals, and lookups to continue being O(1).